# Form with multiple radio buttons of the same name

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, radio-button, model-binding

I am currently writing a program that compares data from multiple databases based on primary keys (I am using VS17 with an MVC architecture using C# razor pages and HTML). To keep it short, my program displays data fields from the same table in multiple databases (the theory being that there are mis-matched records between the different DBs) which I compare using the primary key. I display them as radio buttons so that the user can select the correct value, which will then update the databases accordingly.

I POST the form data and use model binding so that I can create lists of items that are sent to my controllers. This is because I am sending varying amounts of data to the controller, and therefore they must have the same name for the model binding to work correctly (or at least as far I understand it).

The problem I run into is with this specific code in my view:

```
@for (int x = 0; x < Model.ContextTables.Count(); x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < Model.ContextTables[x].Count(); y++)
    {
        if (Model.ContextTables[0][y] != Model.ContextTables[x][y])
        {
            if (x == 1)
            {
                <h5>Column: @Model.Columns[y]</h5>
                <input name="Update_Columns" id="Update_Columns" type="hidden" value=@Model.Columns[y]>
                <text>@Model.DBNames[0]:&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</text><input type="radio" name="Records" value="@Model.ContextTables[0][y]" checked="checked"> @Model.ContextTables[0][y] <br />
            }
            <text>@Model.DBNames[x]:&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</text><input type="radio" name="Records" value="@Model.ContextTables[x][y]" > @Model.ContextTables[x][y] <br />
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially how it works is that if there are 2 (or more) columns that are mismatched, it creates more sets of Radio buttons.

For example, let's say we have the primary Key "Stack Overflow" and between 2 databases, the variables "C#" and "HTML" are different. My web page looks more or less like this:

> PRIMARY KEY: Stack Overflow
>
> DISCREPANCIES:
>
> > C#
> >
> > > t1- "value 1"
> > >       t2- "value 2"
> >
> > HTML
> >
> > > t1-"value 1"
> > >       t2-"value 2"

With radio buttons where the - characters are next to the values. When there is only one mismatched column, this approach works, but when there are 2 or more I can only select 1 radio button out of all of the lists (this is not intended, but I know it is because the "name" of all of my radio buttons is the same).

The intended performance is that each column has it's own separate set of radio buttons, but they most be POSTed to the same name as to create a list (as I mention above). This is because the Action methods cannot take infinitely varying inputs without it being as a list.

For example, if I selected C#, value1 and HTML, value1 the intended result is to have both mapped to form data with the name "Records" such that Records[0] would output value1 from the C# column and Records[1] would output value1 from the HTML column when used in the controller.

What I'm essentially asking for is help/a fix, whether it be with C#, Javascript, J-Query or even in the HTML itself (PHP is not possible), to remedy this issue.

I realize this might seem scatterbrained and messy, but I've been working on this entire project for about a week and a half and my brain is completely fried. If there is anything I can do to provide extra clarity, I would be more than happy to. Thanks!

Comment: Damn. With WP, MVVM and it's Templates this would be really easy. There are only two ways I can think off: 1. Tags. All WinForms controls have a "Tag" property that takes any object. Even handlers will need to do some casting to get to it from the sender sender, but it can help identification in such a case. 2. Generate those buttons Dynamically. Store the array with References with the Data.

Comment: You will never get this to work with your current implementation (at least not without hacks). And all that conditional code belongs in your controller, not in the view. Create a view model to represent your data and strongly bind to it using the `HtmlHelper` methods.

Comment: If you want an answer to this, show your controller methods (both GET and POST) and your model that your passing to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ever runs into a similar situation, I ended up using drop down menus with the same "select" name, and it works just as I intended. Thanks for the help all!